# POST parameters using wrong encoding in JSF 1.2

Tags: jsf, utf-8, character-encoding, facelets, tomcat7

I'm having a problem with charset encoding in my web application (JSF 1.2, Spring and Tomcat 7), and I've ran out of ideas of what to test to see where it is going wrong.

Whenever I submit something like 'çã' I get 'Ã§Ã£': that means my data POSTed as **UTF-8** is being converted to ISO-8859-1 somewhere in the JSF life cycle.

I know that the wrong conversion is UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 cause it's the same output for:

```
System.out.println(new String("çã".getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1"));
```

I believe that the wrong conversion is somewhere in the JSF life cycle (can it be before?) cause I set up a validator in my MB:

```
public void debugValidator(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object object) throws ValidationException {
    System.out.println("debug validator:");
    System.out.println(object);
    System.out.println("\n");
    throw new ValidationException("DEBUG: " + object.toString());
}
```

and its message returns as: "DEBUG: Ã§Ã£"

- I have in all my .xhtml pages the first line as `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`.
- I'm using Facelets, which according to [BalusC's article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) uses UTF-8 by default
- So it wouldn't need but I set up anyway, Spring's `CharacterEncodingFilter` in my *web.xml* to set the request character encoding to UTF-8.
- I put `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` in Tomcat's `server.xml` file, just to guarantee
- It is not my browser's fault, it prints the same thing in the console, and my environment is all **UTF-8**.

Do you have any idea of what more can I test? What could be my wrong assumption?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BalusC's answer helped me to better understand the problem, but what solved it for me was putting the Character Encoding Filter as **the FIRST filter in the chain** (putting it above all the others in the *web.xml* file).

This is the filter I used:

```
<!-- filter enforcing charset UTF-8 - must be first filter in the chain! -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>utf-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Apparently, the data was read before the parameter was set by the filter.
I got the hint from this page: http://tech.top21.de/techblog/20100421-solving-problems-with-request-parameter-encoding.html

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 3):

The symptoms indicate that the browser has sent the data using ISO-8859-1 encoding instead of UTF-8. This in turn means that the HTTP response `Content-Type` header is not been set with the proper `charset` attribute. In for example Firebug, you can find it out as follows:

[image]

You're right that Facelets uses UTF-8 by default. But very early versions of Facelets weren't programmed to use UTF-8 by default. See also among others [issue 46](http://java.net/jira/browse/FACELETS-46) and [issue 53](http://java.net/jira/browse/FACELETS-53). Facelets is currently at [1.1.15.B1](http://www.mvnsearch.org/maven2/com/sun/facelets/jsf-facelets/).

As to your attempts to fix it, the presence of the XML prolog is not strictly necessary and its encoding isn't used in any way to set the response encoding, it's only used by the XML parser to decode the inputstream to characters. Spring's filter is also not necessary, but that it didn't solve the problem after you added it is enough evidence that it's the client who has sent the data as ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Hi, BalusC, thanks for your answer, but I think it's the other way around, cause the Content-type header IS set to UTF-8. Now, I've just checked if I change the encoding in the browser manually to ISO-8859-1, the characters display right in the validator message! Now, what does that mean?

Comment: About Facelets, I am using 1.1.15.B1 btw.

Comment: Is it possible that the browser is sending data as ISO-8859-1, despite _Content-type_ is set to _text/html;charset=UTF-8_?

Comment: I solved the problem putting the Character Encoding Filter as the first in the chain! I feel so stupid now... :D Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Check, if your form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546365/utf-8-text-is-garbled-when-form-is-posted-as-multipart-form-data) form more information

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter;
@Bean
    FilterRegistrationBean<CharacterEncodingFilter> characterEncodingFilter() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        filter.setForceEncoding(true);
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registrationBean.setUrlPatterns(Collections.singletonList("/*"));
        registrationBean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        registrationBean.setFilter(filter);
        return registrationBean;
    }
```

Like Elias Dorneles suggested to put it as the first Filter in the Chain. Here is how you do it when configuring the CharacterEncodingFilter with code.