# Use ISO-8859-1 encoding with JSF 2 on Jboss

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, character-encoding, jboss, mojarra

I have a JSP Page which uses the following directive:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" pageEncoding="iso-8859-1"%>
```

Hence, forms within the page are sent using ISO-8859-1 encoding and the beans receive (in the setXXX() methods) Strings encoded according to this format.

I want to "translate" the JSP into JSF 2, which uses UTF-8 as default. How can I force JSF to use ISO-8859-1 and hence simulate the page directive?

I use Mojarra + richfaces on jboss 6.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Set the `encoding` attribute of the [`<f:view>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/view.html).

```
<f:view encoding="ISO-8859-1">
```

---

Sticking to a non-Unicode encoding is however not recommended anymore these days. Your webapp would be not ready for world domination and you'd risk [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) when an enduser attempts to send Unicode-encoded data anyway (e.g. Hebrew, Cyrillic, Chinese, etc).

Comment: Hi BalusC, Thanks for answering! f:view (I tried to place it in my template directly after html as well as h:body) doesn't seem to help: Firebug keep showing "Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8" for the HTTP header.. Did I miss something? Thx

Comment: Apparently it's been overridden elsewhere. Start debugging at `FaceletViewHandlingStrategy#createResponseWriter()`. I suspect that the `RenderKit` isn't respecting the encoding set by the view. Perhaps RichFaces specific?

Comment: I solved as described below, honestly without understanding what the problem was.. As you say also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609994/post-parameters-using-wrong-encoding-in-jsf-1-2, UTF-8 is default and didn't make sense to use ISO-8859-1. Nevertheless, my beans received Mojibaked german characters. By setting explictly the request's character encoding I solved the problem.. Strange, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really understand the problem, but this allowed me to avoid Mojibake while using UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1:

```
public class EncodingFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (req.getCharacterEncoding() == null) {
            req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

Strangely, without this filter I got Mojibakes although I didn't specify any kind of encoding. I also noticed that (filterConfig.getInitParameter("encoding")) in the init() method always returned null.