# URI Decoding doesn't work in MultipartConfig files

Tags: java, utf-8, uri, decode, multipartconfig

I have used this code to decode a URI string:
`java.net.URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("comment"), "UTF-8")`.  and it works. e.g.

> Input: cl%C4%81mor
>
> Output: clāmor

But when I use `@MultipartConfig` in my java servlet file, this happens:

> Input: cl%C4%81mor
>
> Output: cl%C4%81mor

I am not sure why this didn't work. Can you tell me why this happened and/or how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What ,makes you think that the input is `cl%C4%81mor` in the second case?

Comment: @MauricePerry it is just an example of the input and output of code, they are two separate things, not linked together

Comment: The `URLDecoder` is used to decode URL parts. In the case of a multipart data, the parameters are sent with a POST, and are not part of the URL.

Comment: And even with a GET, request.getParameter should return the decoded parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that `@MultipartConfig` changes the default request encoding in your setup? Can you check what `request.getCharacterEncoding()` returns UTF-8? Is the value returned from `request.getParameter("comment")` different after you add `@MultipartConfig`.

It would be easier to answer if you would provide more information about your setup. If you are using Spring with JEE annotations maybe you want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055025/how-to-change-the-character-encoding-for-servlet-3-0-spring-mvc-multipart-upload).