# Charset encoding for non English characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

I am getting filename from file obj in javascript and sending the same to server using AJAX.

```
var uploadFile = document.getElementById("uploadFile");
var filename = uploadFile.files[0].name;
```

The problem is non English characters found in filename such as 'çõ' and the chars converted to "�". I also set "Content-Type=text/html; charset=UTF-8" in the page.

How can I solve this problem?

Note: This problem occurs only in windows laptops

Comment: Where do the chars become unreadable? If it's in the server, it's a server problem, not a js problem.

Comment: The filename converted to unreadable in js and the converted value sending to server.

I have seen in Developer Console -> Network -> Headers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546365/utf-8-text-is-garbled-when-form-is-posted-as-multipart-form-data

Comment: UTF-8 needs to be all the way through your system -- the files you read need to be in UTF-8, as do the actual program files. The database encoding too. And the encoding specified in the `content-type`. If you have a mismatch of encoding types anywhere through your system, it can result in this kind of error.

Comment: I think this is not a server side problem. Because, if it's a server side problem, the encoding issue will occur for all users.

But, this problem occurs only for some users.

Comment: [JavaScript uses UTF16](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.16).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:

```
filename = unescape(encodeURIComponent(filename));
```