# Sending files and text with AJAX + multipart form data + UTF-8 encoding

Tags: ajax, encoding, utf-8

I've been all day trying to make the client send AJAX requests with UTF-8 encoding in FormData() objects. I'm using Sping MVC on the server side, but that doesn't apply in this case, since:

1. I can POST to the server non-multipart requests, and I can capture the request and see:

   ```
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
   ```

   and I also can see the characters encoded OK (á, é, í, ó, ú).
2. If I POST using AJAX + file upload + FormData, using the following code:

   ```
   var data = new FormData();
   data.append('body', jq("#sp_body").val());
   data.append('signature', jq("#sp_signature").val());
   data.append('subject', jq("#sp_subject").val());
   data.append('email', jq("#sp_email").val());
   data.append("file", jq("#sp_file")[0].files[0]);
   jq.ajax({
       url: contextPath + "/jobs/" + job + "/sendmail",
       data: data,
       cache: false,
       dataType: 'text',
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
       type: 'POST',
       success: function(result){
           data = jq.parseJSON(result);
           if (data["statusCode"] == "success") {
               jq("#save_status").html("Email sent!").show().delay(5000).fadeOut(200);
           } else {
               jq("#save_status").html(data["errors"]).show().delay(5000).fadeOut(200);
           }
       },
       error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           alert(xhr.status);
           alert(thrownError);
       }
   });
   ```

   Then I capture the request and I see:

   ```
   Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------279972256522979
   ```

   But no UTF-8 in the header, and the non-latin characters are garbled.

The question is, how can I POST using FormData (since I want to POST strings and a file at the same time), having UTF-8 encoding set?

I've read [UTF-8 text is garbled when form is posted as multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546365/utf-8-text-is-garbled-when-form-is-posted-as-multipart-form-data) but that didn't help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uploading both data and files in one form using Ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax)

Comment: @DallaRosa Nope, I've read all 30-40 topics about the question, none of them helped me to solve the problem, and the topic you point at it's just about sending both things in a single AJAX request, which I'm already doing "successfully", except for the encoding. The HTTP page has also the meta header setting `charset=utf-8`.

Answer (score 2):

In your servlet, you have to set the encoding again:

```
public void extractRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    if (request != null) {
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        if (isMultipart) {
            FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            List<FileItem> items = null;
            try {
                items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            }
            catch (FileUploadException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = itr.next();
                if (item.isFormField()) {
                    String name = item.getFieldName();
                    String value = item.getString("UTF-8");
                ...
                ...
```

In your html:

```
<form id="formid" action="<yourpath>" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

And of course, if you are using a database, same thing has to be set there as well

Do let me know if this helps; otherwise we can look at other areas.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I finally made it work. Do you know what the problem was? Well, when I deployed the app on the server, everything worked as expected. It turns out that the Eclipse IDE + Tomcat tandem under Windows that was causing trouble (couldn't find the exact reason, as I took the time to have a look and change wherever needed the config files), but when I deployed the WAR on the server, everything went OK.

Comment: Great to hear it's working, and thanks for sharing your solution here :)