# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when decrypting String with special character

Tags: java, gwt, encryption, bouncycastle, tripledes

When decrypting a String with [`com.googlecode.gwt.crypto.client.TripleDesCipher#decrypt`](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-crypto/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/googlecode/gwt/crypto/client/TripleDesCipher.java?r=45) the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -59 
at com.googlecode.gwt.crypto.bouncycastle.util.encoders.HexEncoder.decode(HexEncoder.java:106) 
at com.googlecode.gwt.crypto.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex.decode(Hex.java:86)
at com.googlecode.gwt.crypto.client.TripleDesCipher.decrypt(TripleDesCipher.java:51)
```

The String that is passed to the method contains a special character.

Has anyone of you encountered such an error before?

---

The String that is passed to the `decrypt` method contains the special character `Ţ`. It is encoded in **UTF-8** but is somehow parsed by the `TripleDesCipher` as **ISO-8859-1**.

Comment: print the size of string and see what you get? can you check please?

Comment: Add your code snippet from where you are trying to use `TripleDesCipher#decrypt`.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo The size of the String is determined to be 65 although it is 64 characters long. Maybe it's got something to do with the encoding.

Comment: Generally it states that you 're trying to access array index which is not available. So, you need to make sure the size of the array before accessing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the answer the problem was that we read an **UTF-8** String as it was **ISO-8859-1** and passed it to the `decrypt` method.

The wrong encoding was due to a [`multipart/form-data` request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546365/utf-8-text-is-garbled-when-form-is-posted-as-multipart-form-data).

Answer (score 1):

Java is using UTF-16 for its own encoding: most of the Character will be using 16 bits, but there are some exception. When a character can not be encoded in UTF-16, it will be encoded using hi-surrogate (1 char) and low-surrogate (1 char), so taking 2 native Java char space.

You char representation is:

Ţ : LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T WITH CEDILLA (U+0162)       :    feff0162

The java representation will be 2 java native char (0xfeff and 0x0162).
You can detect this behaviour by testing if one character is a high surrogate (in this case it must be immediately followed by a low surrogate).

More info on javadoc:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isHighSurrogate%28char%29

and in general in Character header doc:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

### EDIT

Forget the previous response, it should not linked with data-representation. It seems that any string you want to "decrypt" must be encrypted as Hexadecimal first. So this excludes Ţ as being a potential value in the encrypted data. Your input should be already wrong before giving it to `TripleDesCipher.decrypt` method.

Comment: Maybe I answered a bit fast, you character seems to be in the UTF-16 2-byte coded range: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0162/index.htm