# Special chars in for MultipartFile file name converted into ? in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload

I am wondering why does spring boot convert MultiPartFile file's name special characters into ? (for eg. ééé.pdf gets converted to ???.pdf). Do I need to configure Spring to disabled this behaviour ? I have checked my jvm configuration for file.encoding and it's already set to UTF-8.

I perform the file upload this way :

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public void uploadFile(@RequestParam MultipartFile file){
// todo : ...
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 text is garbled when form is posted as multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/546365/5221149)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

```
 String originalFileName = URLDecoder.decode(file.getOriginalFilename(), "UTF-8");
```

Hope useful for you

Comment: @BOUHOUALID,  you are welcome, don't forget to accept my answer ;)