# Special Characters of MultipartFile file is converted into ? in springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, file-upload, decode, encode

when I upload a file and pass it to Rest Controller the special chars of filename are converted into ? in spring boot .for example ```.pdf is converted into ???.pdf.

before rest call:

```java
for (FileMessageResurce file : files){
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> request = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    request.add("file", file);
    // ...
    call to controller
```

controller class:

```java
    ResponseEntity<SuccessResponse<Tuple>> upload(
    @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample code of the rest controller (configuration & implementation) so that is easier to tell what is wrong?

Comment: can you check it now

Comment: Here you can find a solution to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59512083/14056755

Comment: no I tried ,but didnt worked