# Tomcat UTF-8 encoding glitch

Tags: jquery, ajax, tomcat, encoding, utf-8

I'm having trouble with special characters in my Tomcat projects. I have all of my files in UTF-8 with meta set for UTF-8 and still when I write `łóęążźć` in any form and send it by POST/GET method (I'm doing it by ajax with jQuery) I got something much more like: `[|zB�D`.

How can I fix it? I'm pretty sure it's because of Tomcat (I'm using 6.0 version).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Problems while submitting a UTF-8 form textarea with JQuery/AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751/problems-while-submitting-a-utf-8-form-textarea-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: possible duplicate of [encoding problem in servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296654/encoding-problem-in-servlet) and [Why does POST not honor charset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392610/why-does-post-not-honor-charset-but-an-ajax-request-does-tomcat-6)

Comment: Tomcat already have filter that sets character encoding to UTF-8 in conf/web.xml file. You should uncomment filter definition and fiter-mapping tags for `setCharacterEncodingFilter`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that jquery's ajax() function will always transmit data with UTF-8 encoding.

In Tomcat, it's best to set the `uRIEncoding` option of the connector to `UTF-8` (in server.xml). This is mainly for the encoding of the URLs but it seems to affect the encoding used with POST request (url encoded) as well:

```
<Connector
    port="8080"
    redirectPort="8443"
    uRIEncoding="UTF-8"
    maxThreads="100">
```